# Improve class using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a lot of identical classes. I want to improve it using generics:

```
public class PingInitializer extends AbstractHandler implements    DataWarehouseInitializer<PingInteraction, PingInvocation> {

    @Handler
    @Override
    public PingInteraction handle(Message message) throws IOException, MessageException {
        checkMessageIsNotNull(message);
        PingInvocation invocation = construct(message.getBody().toString());
        l.debug("handling in initializer...  {}", invocation);
        return new PingInteraction(invocation);
    }

    public PingInvocation construct(String message) throws IOException, MessageException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PingInvocation invocation;
        try {
            invocation = mapper.readValue(message, PingInvocation.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new MessageException("Can't deserialize message", e);
        }
        return invocation;
    }
}
```

I want to create new abstract class AbstractInitializer and all child class just have to specify generic type:

```
public abstract class AbstractInitializer<INTERACTION, INVOCATION> extends AbstractHandler {

    @Handler
    public INTERACTION handle(Message message) throws IOException, MessageException {
        checkMessageIsNotNull(message);
        INVOCATION invocation = construct(message.getBody().toString());
        l.debug("handling in initializer...  {}", invocation);
        return **new INTERACTION(invocation)**; //HERE!
    }

    public INVOCATION construct(String message) throws IOException, MessageException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        INVOCATION invocation;
        try {
            invocation = mapper.readValue(message, **INVOCATION.class** /*<- and HERE */);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MessageException("Can't deserialize message", e);
        }
        return invocation;
    }
}
```

But I have two compilers error and don't know how to bypass this issue. I mark them in code

Comment: Please , provide your error to us .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java generics are implemented with *type erasure* for compatibility reasons, which ultimately means you cannot use a mere type parameter to instantiate a new object.

What you'll need is to modify `AbstractInitializer` a bit...

```
private final Class<INTERACTION> interactionType;
private final Class<INVOCATION> invocationType;
private final Constructor<INTERACTION> interactionConstructor;

public AbstractInitializer(final Class<INTERACTION> interactionType,
    final Class<INVOCATION> invocationType) throws NoSuchMethodException {
  this.interactionType = interactionType;
  this.invocationType = invocationType;
  interactionConstructor = interactionType.getConstructor(invocationType);
}

public INTERACTION handle(Message message) throws IOException, MessageException,
        InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  checkMessageIsNotNull(message);
  INVOCATION invocation = construct(message.getBody().toString());
  l.debug("handling in initializer...  {}", invocation);
  return interactionConstructor.newInstance(invocation);
}

public INVOCATION construct(String message) throws IOException, MessageException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  INVOCATION invocation;
  try {
    invocation = mapper.readValue(message, invocationType);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new MessageException("Can't deserialize message", e);
  }
  return invocation;
}
```

then, as an e.g.

```
public final class PingInitializer
    extends AbstractInitializer<PingInteraction, PingInvocation> {

  public PingInitializer() {
    super(PingInteraction.class, PingInvocation.class);
  }
}
```

or, you could ditch making it `abstract` and use it like...

```
public static GenericInitializer<A, B> createInitializer(final Class<A> a,
    final Class<B> b) {
  return new GenericInitializer<A, B>(a, b);
}

final GenericInitializer<PingInteraction, PingInvocation> pingInitializer
    = createInitializer(PingInteraction.class, PingInvocation.class);
```

I **believe** this should all be possible. I probably made some dumb errors, however, given I typed this in the response box in a hurry.